# How do I do a sub-select in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am new to SQL server, please can any body help me out how to write this query in LINQ.

```
 SELECT [Plan_Num]
      ,(select top 1 ba_level_code + ' - ' + ba_level_desc from baLevel where ba_level_code = '0' + Level_Num) as [Level]
      ,(select top 1 cast(Column_Num as varchar) + ' - ' + Column_Description from baPlanColumnStructure where Column_Num = CL.Column_Num) as [Column]
      ,[Sort_Order]
  FROM baCodeLibrary CL where code_id = 25468 and isactive = 1 order by [Plan_num]
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont know why I got -ve vote for this. you guys should encourage us to learn something from statckover flow. thanks

Comment: I can't speak for whoever cast that vote, but the stated criteria for downvoting are "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Perhaps you should state your own thoughts on possible solutions and describe the efforts you've made already--that would 1) guide people toward more useful answers, and 2) demonstrate that you're not just asking for someone to do the work for you.

Comment: While I think you might have been able to find some useful information by doing some more in depth search, I don't think this is a bad question.  Especially if you are completely new to Linq.  It summarizes the basics of asking, "How do I do a sub-select in Linq?".  +1

Comment: BTW, don't forget to upvote @Alducci's answer (even though he beat me to a VERY similar answer).  It will help you recover your lost points :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for something like this

```
var query = from cl in context.BaCodeLibrary
            where cl.code_id == 25468 && cl.isactive == 1
            orderby cl.Plan_num
            select new
            {
              Level = (from ba in context.baLevel
                       where ba.ba_level_code == ("0" + ba.Level_Num)
                       select ba.ba_level_code + " - " + ba.ba_level_desc).Take(1),

              Column = (from ba in context.baPlanColumnStructure 
                        where ba.Column_Num == cl.Column_Num
                        select ba.ba_level_code + " - " + ba.ba_level_desc).Take(1),

               Sort_Order = cl.Sort_Order
            }
```